# Не перезапускается цикл While

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Сделал игру по угадыванию рандомных чисел, небольшой кусок закинул в цикл while, чтобы игру можно было перезапускать и играть сколько угодно раз, но цикл не перезапускается. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
import random as rn

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.output_data()
    def output_data(self):
        print('Name:', self.name, 'Age:', self.age)
player1 = Player(input('Player 1:\nName: '), input('Age: '))
player2 = Player(input('Player 2:\nName: '), input('Age: '))

print("Game's Rule:")
print('You need to pick right number to win')
while True:
    userchoice = int(input('Введите уровень сложности:\n1 - range(1,5)\n2 - range(1,10)\n3 - range(1,20)'))

    if userchoice == 1:
        rang = '1-5'
    elif userchoice == 2:
        rang = '1-10'
    elif userchoice == 3:
        rang = '1-20'

    ans1 = int(input(f'Player 1: Type your choice(number {rang}): '))
    ans2 = int(input(f'Player 2: Type your choice(number {rang}): '))

    if userchoice == 1:
        RandomNum = rn.randint(1, 5)
    elif userchoice == 2:
        RandomNum = rn.randint(1,10)
    elif userchoice == 3:
        RandomNum = rn.randint(1,20)
    else:
        print('Выберите число от 1 до 3.')
        exit()
    rightans = print('Right answer is - ', RandomNum ,'!')

    if ans1 == RandomNum:
        print('1 player is right!')
    elif ans2 == RandomNum:
        print('2 player is right!')
    elif ans1 and ans2 == RandomNum:
        print('Both answers is right!')
    else:
        print("Nobody don't right")

    ch = print(int(input('Try again?\n 1 - Yes\n 2 and etc. - No\n')))
    if ch == 1:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `ch = print(...` — функция print всегда возвращает `None`, а значит условие `if ch == 1` всегда будет ложным

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)

Comment: Да, `print` там лишний. А ещё непонятно, зачем у вас `exit()` внезапно

Comment: exit() я добавлял чтобы программа завершилась при неправильном вводе значения, ну можно было просто break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам правильно указали, функция `input()` не требует при себе функцию `print()`. Поэтому нужно сделать так:

```
ch = int(input('Try again?\n 1 - Yes\n 2 and etc. - No\n'))
```

Ваш код выходил из цикла, потому что, как верно заметили, `print()` всегда возвращает `None`, если мы записываем его в переменную либо же выводим, соответственно условие `if ch == 1` всегда было ложно.

Comment: Дал ответ только дабы закрыть вопрос)

Comment: Ну и чуть поподробней разъяснить